# событие .click jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ссылка:

```
 <a href="#" class="inventory_item_link"></a>
```

Обработка события:

```
$('.inventory_item_link').click(function(){
        console.log('КЛИК');
    });
```

Не срабатывает, в консоль не отзывается.

Comment: у меня срабатывает.
Проверте на https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извечная проблема. А данное решение универсально - и таким образом даже более правильно навешивать события, не только при использовании ajax но и если вы будете .append('HTML CODE') или что-либо добавляющее на страницу новые элементы делать.

Необходимо события навешивать не на элемент, на сам документ

```
$('#element').on('click', function(){alert('click')})
```

а в функции on указывать при клике на какой элемент в этом документе производить то что вам нужно

```
$(document).on('click', '#element', function(){alert('click')})
```

Это из-за того, что события вешаются на те элементы, которые есть на странице на момент вызова `.on()`, но если вы подгружаете какие-либо элементы ajax'om, то раньше то их не существовало, вот события на них и не привязаны. Либо можно перенавешивать все события после того как элементы вставились на страницу, что нецелесообразно, проще чутка видоизменить функцию в самом начале.